# If $Q$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $U$ and $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an ONB of $U$ with $Qe_n=λ_ne_n$, then $Q^{-1}e_n=\frac 1{λ_n}e_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $U$ be a Hilbert space
- $Q$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $U$
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$ with $$Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$

> Since $Q$ is injective on $\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp$ and $U=\ker Q+\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp$, $$Q^{-1}:=\left(\left.Q\right|_{\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp}\right)^{-1}$$ is a well-defined mapping $Q(U)\to\left(\ker Q\right)^\perp$. Now I would like to show that $$Q^{-1}e_n=\frac 1{\lambda_n}e_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\text{ with }\lambda_n>0\;.$$

How can we do that?

Comment: If $\lambda_n > 0$, then $Qe_n = \lambda e_n \in \overline{\mathcal{R}(Q) }= \mathcal{N}(Q)^{\perp}$ So $Q^{-1}$ is defined on $Qe_n$ and is given by $Q^{-1}(\lambda_n e_n) =Q^{-1}Qe_n = e_n$, or $Q^{-1}e_n = \frac{1}{\lambda_n}e_n$.

Comment: @TrialAndError I don't know what $\overline{\mathcal{R}(Q)}$ is. However, I've noticed that $Qe_n\not\in\ker Q$ and hence $Qe_n$ is an element of $(\ker Q)^\perp$, if $\lambda_n>0$. I suppose (and you may confirm) that this implies that $\left\{e_n:\lambda_n>0\right\}$ can be completed to an ONB of $(\ker Q)^\perp$ (but *how*?). Besides that, I've noticed that $Q^{-1}$ is the real inverse of $\left.Q\right|_{(\ker Q)^\perp}$ and hence (since $Qe_n\in(\ker Q)^\perp$) $Q^{-1}Qe_n=e_n$, if $\lambda_n>0$. I missed the crucial point $Qe_n\in(\ker Q)^\perp$. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

They key observation is that if $\lambda_n=0$ then $Qe_n=0$, and that 
$$
\ker Q=\overline{\text{span}}\,\{e_n:\ \lambda_n=0\},\ \ \ \ (\ker Q)^\perp=\overline{\text{span}}\,\{e_n:\ \lambda_n>0\}.
$$
To check this, let $x\in U$. We can write, since $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis, 
$$
x=\sum_n\alpha_n\,e_n.
$$
Then 
$$
Qx=\sum_n\alpha_n\lambda_n\,e_n=\sum_{n:\ \lambda_n>0}\alpha_n\lambda_n\,e_n.
$$
If $x\in\ker Q$, then $0=Qx$, so $\alpha_n\lambda_n=0$ for all $n$ such that $\lambda_n>0$. Thus, $\alpha_n=0$ and so 
$$
x=\sum_{n:\ \lambda_n=0}\alpha_ne_n\in\overline{\text{span}}\,\{e_n:\ \lambda_n=0\}.
$$
If $x\in(\ker Q)^\perp$, then $\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$ such that $\lambda_n=0$, so $$
x=\sum_{n:\ \lambda_n>0}\alpha_ne_n\in\overline{\text{span}}\,\{e_n:\ \lambda_n>0\}.
$$
The reverse inclusions are trivial.

Now, on $(\ker Q)^\perp$, we have 
$$
Qx=\sum_{n:\ \lambda_n>0}\alpha_n\lambda_n\,e_n.
$$
So the map $Q^{-1}:Qx\longmapsto x$ is given by 
$$
Q^\dagger \left(\sum_{n:\ \lambda_n>0}\alpha_n\lambda_n\,e_n\right)=\sum_{n:\ \lambda_n>0}\alpha_n\,e_n.
$$
In particular, $Q^\dagger (\lambda_n e_n)=e_n$, so 
$$
Q^\dagger e_n=\frac1{\lambda_n}\,e_n.
$$

*(I have used the notation $Q^\dagger $ for the Moore-Penrose inverse, since $Q^{-1}$ is usually reserved for the actual inverse)*